# Making a screenshot scroll inside an iphone container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a screenshot scroll-up inside an iphone. I have an html like this :

```
<div class="iphone-container">
   <img src="images/partenaires.jpg"  class="partner-img"alt="">
 </div>
```

and my css :

```
  .iphone-container {
      background-image:  url("../images/single-iphone.png");
      background-size: cover;
      height: 530px;
      width: 420px;
      position: absolute;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;

    }

.partner-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 355px;;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-top: 128px;
}
```

the image is scrolling up properly but I want it to disappear when it reaches the top of the screen of the iphone. Because right now it looks like this when I scroll up on the screenshot :

[image]

What do I need to change in my css and html to achieve the proper result just like in the 5th section of this website :

http://wefoot.co/

link of screenshot :
http://i63.tinypic.com/anc80l.jpg

link of iphone container :
http://i67.tinypic.com/6hhwti.png

Comment: Try replacing both overflows with `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @SaucedApples the image doesnt scroll anymore if I do that

Comment: Can you upload the images and link them here and I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: @SaucedApples just dit that

Comment: Thanks I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is position a div on top of the iphone image that is exactly the size of the screenshot area and then set that div to overflow:scroll.

So kind of like this:

```
<div class="iphone-container">
   <div class="iphone-screenshot-area">
       <img src="images/partenaires.jpg"  class="partner-img"alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

And for the css:

```
.iphone-container {
  background-image:  url("../images/single-iphone.png");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 530px;
  width: 420px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;


}

.iphone-screenshot-area {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px; //Totally guessing here, adjust to proper value after testing
    left:25px; //Also guessing here, adjust to proper value after testing
    width:355px;
    height:490px; //Also guessing here, adjust to proper value after testing
    overflow:scroll;
}
.partner-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 355px;;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.iphone-container {
      background-image:  url("http://s21.postimg.org/hirg419tj/iphone.png");
      background-size: cover;
      height: 790px;/*the height of the iphone image*/
      width: 400px;/*the height of the iphone image*/
      position: relative; 
    }

.text-holder {
   position: absolute;
   width: 336px;/*the width of the iphone-image screen*/
   height: 600px;/* the height of the iphone-image screen*/
   z-index: 2;
   top: 100px;
   left:38px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   overflow-x:hidden;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="iphone-container">
<div class="text-holder">
<img src="http://s12.postimg.org/yvewkodb1/screen_text.png"><!--I didnt use any class for this image but made a div to place it inside the iphone-->
</div><!--close the text-holder div which is the screen of the iphone image-->
</div><!--close the iphone-container div-->
</body>
</html>
```